# Sharepoint edit form cancel not working. IsDlg=1?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Afternoon 
I've been tasked with some changes to someone elses code who is no longer with the company. Nice and challenging!

The previous developer has made a list of links that go to the edit page of the corresponding listitem however when the user wants to cancel they can't.

When i had a look deeper it seems an extra piece of info has been tagged to the URL.

> IsDlg=1

( This is after the ?ID=1&. If i remove this little critter all works as expected!

However the left hand nav shows up on the edit form.

Ideally i would like to keep the form looking as it is(no left hand nav) with the cancel button working.

Has anyone got any ideas? I wouldn't mind just telling the uses that the left hand nav is going to be there but if i can avoid it being there that would be good.

Any help muchly appreciated.

Cheers
   Truez

Comment: IsDlg is the query variable used by SharePoint 2010 to know how to render the master page when in a dialog view (ie. as a modal or a normal page).  Is there any custom code on the edit page for the list?  The cancel button not working on a OOB list/edit page should just work.  (Also have you debugged the JavaScript to see why the dialog isn't closing?)

Comment: There is no custom code from what i can see unless something has been dropped in to the master page. It just seems incredibly funny that when IsDlg=1 the cancel button doesn't work. Nor does the cancel button on the ribbon. I understand that some of the button OOB use Source as a method of getting the URL the page need to return to. Source isn't existant could this be the issue?

Comment: Edit the list settings (Advance Settings I believe) and for the list to not use dialogs and try the cancel button then.  I doubt the problem is with the IsDlg=1 since I have worked with many OOB and heavily customized lists and the cancel button works just fine.

Comment: Cheers Ken i will have a look at this :)

Comment: Hi Truezplaya, Did you get your issue resolve?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran across this enlightening post by David Lozzi "[We all know what IsDlg does...wait, what the...??](http://davidlozzi.com/2014/03/25/we-all-know-what-sharepoint-isdlg-does-wait-what-the/)" So the trick in SharePoint is to use &isdlg=1 (note lowercase)